# How to visit my first route in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to learn Laravel, so I just created my first project in my Sites folder. The folder in which it is in is now `Sites/dump/laravel_test/`. So following the [quickstart docs](http://laravel.com/docs/quick) I made a route in app/routes.php as follows:

```
Route::get('users', function() {
    return 'Users!';
});
```

After saving the file I tried

- `http://localhost/~kramer65/dump/laravel_test/users`
- `http://localhost/~kramer65/dump/laravel_test/public/users`

but unfortunately, I get a 404 for both urls.

Since it's such a simple start, I don't really know what I should be checking. Could anybody give me some tips on what I could be doing wrong here?

[EDIT] 
Turns out I had to give some permissions to app/storage/meta/serv‌​ices.json

I still wonder though, what are the most suitable and safe permissions to use here?

Comment: Try http://localhost/~kramer65/dump/laravel_test/public/index.php/users

Comment: can you tell me what the output is for: http://localhost/~kramer65/dump/laravel_text/public/index.php/users?

Comment: That URL looks a bit strange.. how is your web server set up?  I normally create a local domain (eg. `x.example.com`) and set it's IP to localhost (`/etc/hosts` on linux).  Then create a virtual host in apache to point that domain to the `/public` folder in the Laravel installation... then you just go to `x.example.com/users` to hit your route.

Comment: @AntonioCarlosRibeiro - Ah, in there it said that `file_put_contents(/Users/kramer65/Sites/dump/laravel_test/app/storage/meta/services.json): failed to open stream: Permission denied` So I did a `chmod -R 777` on storage and that fixed it. I know that 777 is wrong, but at least it gave me the possibility to get started. Anybody know which permissions I should set (recursively) to storage to have it functioning well and safely (i.e.: not 777)?

Comment: @msturdy - As you can see in my comment above, I fixed it by setting some permissions. You'r way of doing it sounds interesting though, but that's a next step for me. I'll definitely come back to your command later!